# How to Set Time in QTimeEdit at Run Time in QT?

Tags: qt

How to Set Time in QTimeEdit at Run Time in QT ?

Like I want to Show 17:30 in QtimeEdit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetimeedit.html#time-prop What exactly did you not understand?

example:

```
QTime time(17, 30);
QTimeEdit te;
te.setTime(time);
```

Comment: Acually I have one Qstring which contains time QString strFrom = "17:30" now i want to set time using this.can i do this way ?

Comment: @user I don't mean to be rude but please check the documentation more closely next time. http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtime.html#fromString

Comment: @RedX, it's not the most intuitive thing, even looking at the documentation.  You pretty much have to do `some_time_edit->setTime(QTime::fromString(QString("17:30)))`.  Not exactly succinct, and it involves a QString, QTime, and QTimeEdit.  I've done Qt for several years and it took me a little bit of time to track down (just now using time boxes). In an ideal world, someone would just be able to say `some_time_edit->setFromString("17:30")`, but it involves documentation on 3 separate classes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following methods:

- setTime ( const QTime & )
- setTimeRange ( const QTime &, const QTime & )
- setTimeSpec ( Qt::TimeSpec )

e.g.:

```
this->time_edit->setTime(QTime(10,17));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply:

[bool QTime::setHMS ( int h, int m, int s, int ms = 0 )](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html#setHMS)

```
QTime tm;
tm.setHMS(10,25,45,0);
```

The result will be "10:25:45"

Cheers.